# Filter top questions by tag

Tags: feature-request, tags, user-interface, tag-watching

Sometime I would like to see only the top questions for my favorite tags.

Is this possible? I searched Meta but did not find any post regarding this.

Comment: Please leave a hint on why there is no response to my question! I expected at least an "Already exists!", a "Why do you want that?!" or at least a "This is dumb!". Thanks!

Comment: I could script this if there was an option in search for `OR`--which there isn't. Most probably this just got neglected. I don't think such a feature exists. I'm converting this to a feature request...

Comment: Yeah, this would be an awesome feature to have. I'd love to be able to look once a week and read the most popular questions on my favorite topics.

Comment: @Igorostrovsky Thanks for your support. That is exactly my use-case as well.